# What's wrong with my Regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a written a `Regex` to check whether the string consists of `9 digits` or not as follows but this always returning me `false` even if I have my string as `123456789`.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(strSSN, " ^\\d{9}$"))
```

Can any one tell what's wrong and also if any better one provide me .. What i am achieving is the string should have only `numeric data` and the length should be `=9`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spaces are significant in regular expressions (and of course, you can't match a space character *before* the start of the string). Remove it and everything should be fine:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(strSSN, "^\\d{9}$"))
```

Also, you generally want to use verbatim strings for regexes in C#, so you don't have to double your backslashes, but this is just a convenience, not the reason for your problem:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(strSSN, @"^\d{9}$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
^\d{9}$
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a whitespace between `"` and `^`. It should be:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(strSSN, "^\\d{9}$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

could it be the space at the beginning of your pattern?  That seems wierd, a space then a number anchored to the start of the line.

This should give you what you want:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(strSSN, "^\\d{9}$"))
```